# Слитное или раздельное написание "от()того, что"

Tags: слитно-раздельно

Подскажите, будьте добры, слитно или раздельно:

> Его руки дрожали от ярости и от()того, что он продрог на морозе.

Answer (score 2):

Слитно: указание на причину (потому, из-за того).

[Вопрос № 301255](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE)

> Добрый день, будьте добры, подскажите, следует здесь писать слитно или
>   раздельно (если уже есть предлог "от"): Его руки дрожали от ярости и
>   от(того), что он продрог на морозе.

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**

> Верно: ...от ярости и оттого, что он продрог на морозе.
>
> ---

[Вопрос № 281500](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=281500)

> Как разграничить *оттого что* и *от того что*? Чем руководствоваться
>   при написании? *Но еще страшнее становилось (от)того, что я не
>   понимала, откуда ждать опасности.*

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**

> Союз *оттого что* можно заменить синонимичным союзом *потому что*.
>   Запятая может ставиться перед союзом или между его частями. Ср.: *я
>   счастлива оттого, что он сказал мне эти слова / я счастлива, оттого
>   что он сказал мне эти слова (= я счастлива потому, что он сказал мне
>   эти слова / я счастлива, потому что он сказал мне эти слова) – многое
>   зависит от того, что он скажет* (здесь сочетание предлога с
>   местоимением от того, заменить союзом потому что невозможно, запятая
>   может быть поставлена только перед что, на что падает ударение).
>
> В приведенном Вами примере используется союз ***оттого что***.

---

***Его руки дрожали от ярости и оттого, что он продрог на морозе.***